# ABORTING: DALVIK: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN dispose_chunk addr=0x0

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm actually facing a problem that I can't solve.
I have a Heap Memory Corruption appearing after about 10 seconds after my app is launched.

I'm working with JNI and I think the problem could come from here :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_net_coop_rouler_motion_MotionActivityEngineProxy_getMotionData(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray bufferOut, jobject annotations)
{
    jbyte *cBufferOut = env->GetByteArrayElements(bufferOut, 0);

    MotionActivityEngine *mae = getMotionActivityEngine(env, thiz);
    bool boolMotionData[16];
    mae->getMotionData(boolMotionData);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        cBufferOut[i] = boolMotionData[i] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass (annotations);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID (clazz, "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;");
    if (mid == 0)
        return;
    std::string a;
    mae->getAnnotations(a, 9);
    jstring _jstring = env->NewStringUTF (a.c_str());
    env->CallObjectMethod (annotations, mid, _jstring);

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bufferOut, cBufferOut, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

Is there something wrong ? Maybe I should release the strings, but I already tried and it didn't seems to work.

Here is my Logcat :

```
12-08 17:50:14.126: A/dalvikvm(10616): @@@ ABORTING: DALVIK: HEAP MEMORY CORRUPTION IN dispose_chunk addr=0x0
12-08 17:50:14.126: A/libc(10616): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 10663 (Thread-13334)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**EDIT**

Here is the code of my getMotionActivityEngine :

```
static MotionActivityEngine * getMotionActivityEngine(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jfieldID fieldId = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "motionActivityEngine", "J");
    jlong value = env->GetLongField(thiz, fieldId);
    return (MotionActivityEngine *)value;
}
```

**EDIT**

This is what I'm doing right before the getMotionData :

```
byte motionData[] = new byte[8];
StringBuffer annotations = new StringBuffer("");
motionActivityEngine.getMotionData(motionData, annotations);
```

Comment: What did you do in getMotionActivityEngine? How did you get the pointer mae? Don't you need to release it?

Comment: I just edited my post to put the getMotionActivityEngine and also what I'm doing before the getMotionData.

Comment: Probably mae is null, or has been released somewhere. Have you checked it?

Comment: I found where the error was coming. My "motionData" array was a size of 8 instead of a size of 16...